# visual studio 2010 jquery and ScriptManager causes an error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

i've just installed new visual studio 2010, and when i create new form and add jquery avaliable and scriptmanager then firefox shows me an eror
Sys.ArgumentException: An element with id 'form1' could not be found. Parameter name: elementOrElementId

form looks like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <div>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post source code and not screen shots which cannot be copy-pasted and making it much more difficult to reproduce your scenario. You expect someone typing all this code manually in order to try to repro?

Comment: ok but there is big problem with posting html code, how should do it? it works great with regular code like C#

Comment: @kosnov, please read the basic formatting tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (or click on the yellow question mark when editing your question)

Comment: Select the HTML and click the { } button to format it specially.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, i did, seems that this is bug in visual studio

Comment: Sys.ArgumentException is a Microsoft JavaScript error, not jquery. You've not done anything yet that uses jQuery. If you deleted the jquery script reference it would still do the same thing.

Comment: i just didn't show you my usage of jquery to show the problem in simple way. I am using ddl which requires script manager, but u want to add some code using jquery not java script or ajax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

do:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also jQuery's `$` function might conflict with MsAjax so make sure you read about [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) if you are planning on using jQuery. Or even better, because you plan to use jQuery throw away MsAjax and script managers. You don't need them.

Comment: Thanks @Darin, this saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Add EnablePartialRendering="false" to the scriptmanager

**Your aspx page will have the below code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>my Test page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false" Width="100%" ShowToolBar="false">
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```